# Singleton sets are a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am tasked with prove the following elementary result. I am concerned about being rigours enough in my proof:

$$a\in S \iff \{a\} \subseteq S $$

**My Attempt:**

Suppose $\{a\} \subseteq S $ . Then every element of $\{a\}$ would be a element of $S$ but  $ a$ is  the only element of $\{a\}$ thus $a \in S$

While I have no qualms about this being true, I am unsure on how to preceed with in a rigorous and verbose manner

I would think the constructing the set $\{a\}$ and noting that $a \in S$( by Hpothesis) so every element of $\{a\}$ would be an element of $S$ and thus $\{a\} \subseteq S $  would be the way to go.

Comment: The statements$\left\{ a\right\} \subset S$ and $a\in S$ are both
equivalent to the statement $\forall x\in\left\{ a\right\} \; x\in S$.

Comment: @drhab How do I prove that ?

Comment: The relation $A\subseteq B$ is actually defined as $\forall x\left[x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B\right]$
so there is nothing to prove when it comes to the equivalence of $\left\{ a\right\} \subseteq S$
with the statement $\forall x\in\left\{ a\right\} \left[x\in S\right]$.
A statement like 'set $a$ has the property...' can be translated
as: 'all elements of $\left\{ a\right\} $ have the property...' .
Here the property you are dealing with is to be an element of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

What you said is basically right, although you want to make sure to prove both directions of the implication.  So,

> By the definition of the subset relation, $\{a\}\subseteq S$ if and only if every element of $\{a\}$ is an element of $S$.  By the definition of the singleton set, the only element of $\{a\}$ is $a$.  Therefore, $\{a\}\subseteq S$ if and only if $a\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$I would prove this rigorously as follows:
$$\calc
\{a\} \subseteq S
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\subseteq\;$}
\langle \forall x : x \in \{a\} : x \in S \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\{\ldots\}\;$}
\langle \forall x : x = a : x \in S \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: one-point rule}
a \in S
\endcalc$$

Comment: This is not any more rigorous than what he suggested,it only includes additional sentences about what you are doing.Thwarting the power of natural language with symbolism is absurd

Comment: @VanioBegic Thanks for explaining your downvote. However, I don't see the need for calling this style of proof "absurd". As someone who is very familiar with this style, as detailed in e.g. "A Logical Approach to Discrete Math" and [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html), in my experience the shape of the formulas often really helps shape the design of proofs, and makes a proof like mine easy to write and verify, without making it longer. _Ignoring the power of symbols is to limit oneself._

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\{a\}\subset S$.
We have that $a\in\{a\}$.
Since $\{a\}\subset S$, it follows that $a\in S$.

Suppose that $a\in S$.
Take any $x\in\{a\}$.
It follows that $x=a$.
Since $a\in S$, it follows that $x\in S$.
We have shown that $\forall x\ (x\in\{a\}\implies x\in S)$, so $\{a\}\subset S$.

If this is not what you need, then perhaps you may find inspiration here:
http://www.apronus.com/provenmath/btheorems.htm

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Proposition. } a\in S \iff \{a\} \subseteq S $

$\textit{Proof.}$

Let $S$ be a set and let $a\in S$. Consider the set $\{a\}$. Now take the element $a\in \{a\}$. Since $a\in S$ and $a$ is the only element of $\{a\}$ it follows that $\{a\} \subseteq S$. Thus, $a\in S \Rightarrow \{a\} \subseteq S$

Let $\{a\} \subseteq S$. Set-inclusion is defined such that the set $B$ is contained within the set $C$ (i.e. $B\subseteq C$) if and only if $\forall b\in B,b\in C$. Then, since $a\in\{a\}$, it follows that $a$ must be in $S$. Thus, $\{a\} \subseteq S \Rightarrow a\in S$.

Therefore $a\in S \iff \{a\} \subseteq S $.